# I want to evaluate this function in this way but not getting the desired answer. Can anyone please help?

Tags: plotting, calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration

I am trying to do the integration in this way. This is just an example but I want to do something like this, the output of the first integration will be in the second integration. I hope it is clear from this. Is there any way to do it?

```
f[r_] := Sqrt[r^2 + r^3];
p71[r_]:=r^2
a1 = 5.93999103;
g91 = { };
While[a1 <= 20,
  p31 = NIntegrate[f[r], {r, 5.93999103, a1}];
  p41 = p71[a1]*p31;
  
  AppendTo[g91, p41];
  a1 += 0.1];

p318[nu_] := 
  NIntegrate[((4*nu)/((Exp[(nu)/(g91)^(1/4)]) - 1)), {r, 
    5.939991023, \[Infinity]}];
Plot[p318[nu], {nu, 0.001, 10}]
```

Comment: `p71` is undefined

Comment: @yarchik sorry for that. I edited it.

Comment: When I paste your code into a fresh notebook and change only the last line to `Table[p318[nu],{nu,1,10}]` I get a flood of error messages, most of which look like they are from dividing by zero. Is that what you see? Can you track down why you are getting those?

Comment: @Bill that is only because the first element in g91 is zero. If we ignore that and do the integration then still I am not getting anything. so I do not know if this is the correct way to do it. Since g91 is an array which has elements at every r and I want to integrate new function.

Comment: `g91`is a numerical list of numbers and occurs in your last integral `Exp[(nu)/(g91)^(1/4)]` . What could be the purpose of such a construct?

Comment: @UlrichNeumann there are two integration and the answer of the first integration will be put in the second one to integrate it again over r. since the functions are complicated for my case , I am doing numerical integration. so you can understand that first integration is from 5.93999103 to r and then second integration is from 5.93999103 to \infinity.

Comment: @AKU That's already clear. Check `g91` just before defining the second integral. Probably it should be a function[r] I think.

Comment: @UlrichNeumann so you can just put g91[r] in place of g91 and it will work? I tried that but it did not work. I am not even sure that it is the correct way or I have to do any interpolation or extrapolaion.

Answer (score 1):

If I correctly understand your calculations, you are looking for a function `a0= 5.93999103; F[a1]=a1^2 Integrate[f[r],{r,a0,a1}]`?

Instead of `While` try `NDSolve`:

```
a0= 5.93999103;
f[r_] := Sqrt[r^2 + r^3];
D[a1^2 Integrate[f[r],{r,a0,a1}],a1]; (* F'[a1]*)
```

`F'[a1]` depends on `F[a1]`

```
ode=Derivative[1][F][a1] == a1^2 f[a1] + (2 F[a1])/a1     
g91 = NDSolveValue[{ode, F[a0] == 0}, F, {a1, a0, 20}] (* function g91[a1]*)
Plot[g91[a1], {a1, a0, 20}, AxesLabel -> {a1, "g91[a1]"}]
```

[image]

Knowing `g91` it's possible (hopefully) to evaluate the second integral.

**But second integral doesn't converge!**